# Causes of upward trend in median first marriage age in USA?

Tags: reference-request, labor-economics, data-request, behavioral-economics

I found a [chart here](http://www.infoplease.com/ipa/A0005061.html) of median age at first marriage by year from 1890 to 2010. It looks like it dips to a low during the 60s then has an upward trend until 2010.[image]

As an answer, I'm looking for any previous economic research about the causes of this trend. I'm also looking for data and theories that might shed light to this trend.

And if anyone can give a summary of proposed causes of this trend, I'd also appreciate that.

**Background/side note**
There are other demographic trends coming from that pivotal time too, like more women in the work force, more women in college. I would have thought this kind of integration would make the marriage market more efficient and lower/hold constant that age. I guess there are changing preferences and less demand for marriage until later ages nowadays? People fall in love later? Or school and work are bad places to find a partner? Those are just some of my thoughts I'd like to get more info on.

**extra note** I disagree with people who don't include marriage as an acceptable topic for economics. But they might be kind of right. Marriage is a topic for sociology. To clear this up though, I'm just looking for the information that the discipline of economics can provide. So no, this isn't a sociology question, even though the two overlap. See comments below. Feel free to edit this question if it needs further clarification or narrowing, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as it stands, it's a sociology question, not an economics question.

Comment: What the heck, you don't think there are any papers about economic theories of matching that can apply here? Or any behavioral economics papers about marriage decision that apply here or exist? Or any data about marriage that are tied to other economic factors? Does marriage not have substitutes or compliments? Does it not provide utility?

Comment: @EnergyNumbers it's one thing to say this is a sociology question. And yeah, in a lot of ways it is a sociology question. But it's another thing to say it's "not an economics question". In that point, you are dead wrong my friend.

Comment: Unless there really aren't any economics research papers on marriage.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers [The Effect of Age at First Marriage on Career Development and Wages](http://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/working_papers/2004/RAND_WR207.pdf)

Comment: @ColeTrumbo Your first comment is pretty weird. You could claim that "Which shade of blue do people like most" is an economic question as pretty colors provide utility, preference is a behavioral aspect, and dark blue is a close substitute of navy blue. Don't get upset if people disagree with you, the question is borderline on topic.

Comment: I think this question is clearly *on* topic here. This is a request for economic literature that uses the tools of economics to understand marriage decisions. There is a large such literature dating back, at least, to Gary Becker's 1974 "A Theory of Marriage" in the Journal of Political Economy (a part of the body of work on non-market behaviour that won him the Nobel prize *in economics*). The idea that "it's not economics unless there's a price" has been out of fashion for some time.

Comment: @denesp you're right, I shouldn't get upset. What got to me was the vote to close. I thought that was harsh, and frustrating to not be able to get any answer. This site is like my main source of answers for econ stuff, so I get bummed when I get shut down here. But I'll try not to in the future.

Comment: Putting questions on hold isn't shutting them down. It's simply a way of preventing answers being posted to a question that needs to be edited. We do that to save the time and effort of the answerers: editing a question can significantly change how people interpret a question, making earlier answers irrelevant.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers Ok cool, thanks for clearing that up. Now I get you. My question wasn't clear enough and came off wrong. I understood it, but now i realize other people didn't/wouldn't, and it did need some editing.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers Could you, next time that happens, just ask some clarification first, like make the necessary assumptions so that it can be understood as economics question, then ask if you're interpretation is right? Then the editing would be smoother,  I would know what's unclear, I wouldn't feel shut down,  etc.

Comment: Putting things on hold when question are unclear is how the system is designed to work, and it works really well. It needs five users, or one moderator, to put a question on hold, and as soon as it's edited, it goes into the queue to be reviewed for reopening. Although the way we do things will seem odd, and occasionally even harsh, at first, as you get used to them, you come to understand that these ways are what makes the network so successful at quality Q&A.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers, so no? You won't ask any clarifying questions in the comments; you will just vote to close first? I'm not asking you to not put things on hold. Like I said earlier, I get you. And I like the quality of this community and all that goes into monitoring and moderating it. I needed help from moderators when I first started using these sites, and I still do. I'm glad you would put my question, or anyone's on hold if it's not on topic. But, as a small first measure of clarification, I'm asking for some questions in the comments before going straight to a vote to close.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers and I think I get why you restated the reason for voting to close and explaining how a question gets put on hold. I think it's because you want me to know why so that I don't take it personal or get emotional. Duly noted. I won't. No hard feelings. I appreciate you. Sorry for reacting so intense earlier. And I don't mean to egg you on with my earlier comment. I actually want to know, to learn how this works, if questions in the comments are an expected part of the community or the clarification/editing process. You didn't mention them in your explanation of closing questions.

Comment: Thanks for being so understanding. The vote to close does contain a description of what the vote means, so in most cases, adding a further comment is redundant - there's no point in writing a comment that just says what the vote-to-close text says. We all have limited time to spend on janitorial tasks here, and voting to close is a very time-efficient way to indicate why the question may need work. That said, people will provide further comments as time allows and as appropriate in the circumstances.